# Why does not Qt app on my android device support utf-8 characters

Tags: android, qt, unicode, utf-8

I installed Qt creator for android in my PC (windows 7 x64) and downloaded all prerequisites and perform all steps in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_nkhlhBwkjk .

I developed a simple app in Qt creator with one MainWindow and a QtWidgets/QLabel within it. Text of this Qlabel is written by utf-8 encoding.

When i run the app in my PC(win), no problem exist but when i build and run on my android mobile, all text of label not display correct. it display characters like rectangles.

what is the problem reason? am i missing a work like configuring a thing in Qt creator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is solved. the problem was not unicode. I changed my font used in app (MS Shell Dlg 2) to Tahoma and embedded it in resource file.